# Menu without submenus using resource script or CMenu functions

Tags: c++, windows, menu, mfc, cmenu

I want to create a menu without any submenus.
A common way to create a menu is:

```
BEGIN
   POPUP "File"
   BEGIN
      MENUITEM "Copy", IDM_EDIT_COPY
      MENUITEM "Paste", IDM_EDIT_PASTE
   END
   ...
END
```

Now I just want **"File"** without the submenus **"Copy"** and **"Paste"**.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think I've *ever* seen an application do this, so I don't know whether it is possible or not, but have you tried BEGIN/MENUITEM/END?

Comment: Yes tried..It doesnot serve the purpose. It created a pop menu with empty submenu.. There is popup present which is empty

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
BEGIN
   MENUITEM "File", ID_FILE
   ...
END
```

?